# Magento "convert quote to order" observer not firing correct method

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Below is the events part of my config file. When a quote item is being converted to order item, I want to set custom options on the products. But, the problem is the method setCustomOptionsOnOrderItem is not getting called when a quote is being converted to an order.

"catalogProductLoadAfter" method is being called instead. Bu, trying to access `$orderItem = $observer->getOrderItem()` in this method is returninn null.

Can anyone please guide what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
<events>
    <customer_login>
        <observers>
            <loginredirect>
                <class>xxxxxx/observer</class>
                <method>xxxxx</method>
            </loginredirect>
        </observers>
    </customer_login>
<catalog_product_load_after>
        <observers>
            <extra_options>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>xxxxxx/observer</class>
                <method>catalogProductLoadAfter</method>
            </extra_options>
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_load_after>  
 <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
        <observers>
            <quoteitem_set_custom_data>
                <class>xxxxx/observer</class>
                <method>setCustomOptionsOnOrderItem</method>
            </quoteitem_set_custom_data>
        </observers>
    </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item> 
</events>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
    <observers>
        <mynamespace_mymodule_sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>setCustomOptionsOnOrderItem</method>
        </mynamespace_mymodule_sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
    </observers>
</sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
```

and in the Observer file:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer
{
    public function setCustomOptionsOnOrderItem(Varien_Event_Observer $o)
    {  
    // do your stuff here
    }
}
```